# Using `SELECT` to call a function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I occasionally encounter examples where `SELECT...INTO...FROM DUAL` is used to call a function - e.g.:

```
SELECT some_function INTO a_variable FROM DUAL;
```

is used, instead of

```
a_variable := some_function;
```

My take on this is that it's not good practice because A) it makes it unclear that a function is being invoked, and B) it's inefficient in that it forces a transition from the PL/SQL engine to the SQL engine (perhaps less of an issue today).

Can anyone explain why this might have been done, e.g. was this necessary in early PL/SQL coding in order to invoke a function? The code I'm looking at may date from as early as Oracle 8.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: I think very old versions of Oracle (such as Oracle 8 and 9), did not actually support assignment with a function.

Comment: As far as I remember, the second syntax is available since 10g. Are you sure it's runnable on 8i?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I know that 9i supported direct assignment from functions (e.g. `a_variable := some_function;`). But 8i may not have - I never had to work with it. Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note that `select function from dual` also ensures that said function doesn't change database state - no commits or other DDL, no DML like update/inserd/delete. I highly doubt that was the reason, though.

Comment: I don't think it has ever been necessary to call functions that way - here is the Oracle 7 documentation for functions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/dcommon/oin/index.htm While it doesn't show an assignment statement, it does show `IF sal_ok(new_sal, new_title) THEN ...`.  I think some programmers just did it that way - possibly a throwback to the language they used before PL/SQL in Forms 2.3 (what was that called?)

Comment: Direct assignment will not cause a context switch from PL/SQL to SQL and back again (unless the function contains SQL code of course) so it should be more efficient than going to `DUAL`.

Comment: Some info on pre-PL/SQL Forms "v2-style" triggers here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/855635?tstart=0

Comment: @TonyAndrews http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/dcommon/oin/index.htm , code in "Avoiding Errors" section shows assigning a variable from a user-defined function `sign()` via `:=`, so it worked in Oracle 7. Thanks for the link by the way, it's fun to read and note the changes made to more modern versions.

Comment: sign() is not a user-defined function, it is a built-in. In Oracle 7.3 functions could only be used in expressions, so valid in IF my_func() = x, but I don't believe they were permitted in simple assignments - hence that silly SELECT FROM DUAL.step we had to take.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton I gave a wrong link somehow (frame-based navigation, grmbl) - the correct one is http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch7.htm#overloading . `SIGN` function is overloaded/redefined with user function in the code snippet and subsequently called inside and outside the scope as `x := SIGN(0);` with different results.

Comment: This sections confirms that `variable := function();` was allowed in Oracle 7: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/PLS23/ch10a.htm#toc098 `expression: This is an arbitrarily complex combination of variables, constants, literals, operators, and function calls. The simplest expression consists of a single variable. For the syntax of expression, see "Expressions" on page 10 - 41. When the assignment statement is executed, the expression is evaluated and the resulting value is stored in the assignment target. The value and target must have compatible datatypes.`

Comment: Maybe someone here still has Oracle 7 and can confirm empirically :-)

Comment: I do still have Oracle 7 on a CD somewhere. Even have an old NT laptop still around to run it on! If the house guests over Christmas get annoying...who knows. :-)

Comment: @MichaelBroughton: post a reminder comment on this message in a couple days and I'll put a 100 rep bounty out for the first person to test calling functions in Oracle 7. :-)

Comment: I don't have any insight on the original source/reason but I know why this still haunts me in 2015/11g - old habits die hard :( A) there is old developers that always do what they have always done and B) there is new developers that just cut and paste without any insight about PL/SQL.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton and all - Merry Xmas! I've posted a 100 rep bounty on the question about using `SELECT some_function INTO a_variable FROM DUAL` - specifically, I'm curious if this form of "function call" was required under Oracle 7. Michael, you'd earlier said you might be able to load Oracle 7 and test this. Well, perhaps this is sufficient motivation..? :-)

Comment: I can imagine a scenario where this kind of code might survive after multiple refactorings, e.g.: version 1: `SELECT DECODE(...) INTO x FROM DUAL;` (required since decode raises PLS-00204 in PL/SQL) which later gets rewritten as a function call; but the author doesn't notice that the query is no longer required.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - our organization didn't start using Oracle until version 8, so I suspect that this is a case of Old Coding Habits Die Hard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This practice dates from **before** PLSQL and Oracle 7. As already mentioned assignment was possible (and of course Best Practice) in Oracle7.

Before Oracle 7 there were two widely used Tools that **needed** the use of **Select ... into var from dual;**

On the one hand there used to be an Oracle Tool called RPT, some kind of report generator. RPT could be used to create batch processes. It had two kinds of macros, that could be combined to achieve what we use PLSQL for today. My first Oracle job involved debugging PLSQL that was generated by a program that took RPT batches and converted them automatically to PLSQL. I threw away my only RPT handbook sometime shortly after 2000.

On the other hand there was Oracle Forms 2.x and its Menu component. Context switching in Oracle Menu was often done with a **Select ... from dual;** I still remember how proud I was when I discovered that an untractable Bug was caused by a total of **6** records in table Dual.

I am sorry to say that I can not proof any of this, but it is the time of year to think back to the old times and really fun to have the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info! BTW - I like your avatar picture. I live near Hinckley, Ohio where turkey vultures (locally called "buzzards") are a local icon (they surf the air currents rising from Hinckley Ridge - which runs right across the road from me) so I see these animals A Lot during summer, which is why I could identify the bird from the picture. I just try to keep moving and hope they don't get impatient :-). Also, my daughter volunteers at a local bird rescue organization that treats some injured buzzards (although their bald eagle is more impressive :-). Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also - thanks for pointing out that some of my colleagues coding habits are even more atrophied than my own! ;-)