# Whats the performance of querying in dual on Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle11g, oracle10g

I was trying to access the time and timezone of a db. The query i had were :

```
select sysdate from dual
```

and

```
select systimestamp from dual
```

What would be the performance over-head of querying these ? I do understand that until 10g these were expensive and starting 11 they were to be in-memory. Would these run in 00:00:01 ?

Comment: "Would these run in 00:00:01" - that's an unusual question. Why do you ask?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't bother of that. Surely is fast.

An idea would be to measure it. Because is fast, let's do it 10000 times and measure the time:

```
declare
t number;
d date;
begin

  t:=dbms_utility.get_time();
  for k in 1..10000 loop
    select sysdate into d from dual;
  end loop;
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.get_time() - t);
end;
/
```

On my machine(with oracle 11.2.0.4) this outputs 16, so 16 milliseconds for 10000 times, that means 0.000016 seconds per operation.

EDIT: Select 1 from dual is faster, the above returning 13 milliseconds. Systimestamp is a little slower than sysdate, with 17.

Answer (score 2):

I stole @FlorinGhita's code and changed it to:

```
declare
  t number;
  d date;
begin
  t := dbms_utility.get_time();

  for k in 1..10000 loop
    select sysdate into d from dual;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.get_time() - t);

  t := dbms_utility.get_time();

  for k in 1..10000 loop
    d := SYSDATE;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.get_time() - t);
end;
```

because I wanted to contrast the amount of time required to do the SELECT with the amount of time required to perform the direct assignment.

The results of five runs of the above were

```
SELECT    Assignment
73        6
84        6
74        6
74        6
74        5
```

Next, my thought was that perhaps there was overhead associated with having the SELECT statement first - so I changed it around so that the assignment loop was done first followed by the SELECT loop:

```
declare
  t number;
  d date;
begin
  t := dbms_utility.get_time();

  for k in 1..10000 loop
    d := SYSDATE;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.get_time() - t);

  t := dbms_utility.get_time();

  for k in 1..10000 loop
    select sysdate into d from dual;
  end loop;

  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.get_time() - t);
end;
```

Five runs of the above gave:

```
 Assignment    SELECT
 5             78
 6             75
 7             72
 6             75
 6             86
```

If I'm reading the above correctly it shows that performing a `SELECT...FROM DUAL` takes more than 10 times LONGER than making a direct assignment.

Takeaway: don't use `SELECT xxxxx INTO zzz FROM DUAL`. Use `zzz := xxxxx` instead.

Timings above were generated by Oracle 11.1

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice test. Just one comment here. The worse timing is not caused by access to dual table, but rather by context which between PL and SQL engine. The same applies to `a := select seq.nextval from dual;` vs. pure `a := seq.nextval;` . The later is newer, simplified syntax.

Comment: Worth reading Bob's thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418779/using-select-to-call-a-function

Comment: @FlorinGhita - I thought this current question was interesting, especially in regards to the question you cited. Thanks for remembering it. :-) I hadn't thought to compare the `SELECT function INTO variable FROM DUAL` to `variable := function` before, so this was a good opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes these was some perfomance improvement implemented in 11g [See this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816/836215). But even in 10g there is no need to worry about performance. Most likely the access to this table will NOT do any disk IO (just one logical read).

Answer (score 0):

I am using `11g`.

Adding to @Florin answer, I repeated the test for 10000 rows, to `get_time` for both the commands, `sysdate` and `systimestamp`.

The output for `sysdate` was same as Florin, `16` but the output for `systimestamp` was `36`.

But when I repeated it for `100000` rows, the output was `185` and `197` respectively.

So to answer your question, **using `sysdate` is definately faster than `systimestamp`.**